# I want to drive individual LEDs (not a ready made matrix) with a MAX7219 IC

Tags: led, matrix, max7219

I want to control 24 single LEDs with a [MAX7219](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max7219-max7221.pdf). I understand the concept of the matrix and I know how to control the MAX7219.

What I don't understand is how to read the datasheet correctly and work out what the specifications of the LEDs need to be.

Answer (score 2):

Table 11 on page 11 gives some values for I<sub>SEG</sub> and V<sub>LED</sub>.
[image]

So if you're using an LED with a forward voltage of 3.0V, use a resistor or 24.5 kOhm for a forward current of 20 mA. You can use any LED with a forward current 10-40 mA and a forward voltage of 1.5-3.5 V.
You can probably go under those values, ie less than 10mA or 1.5V, but you'd have to guess a bit for your value of R<sub>SET</sub>. I wouldn't try and exceed them without using an external driver as the datasheet recomends